# if i click the dialog box,the backgroung layout is going to black color

Tags: android, dialog

I click change password `Button` in one layout. The dialog box should appear in that same layout, but in htc sense the background layout is going to black.

How to resolve this issue?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: May be `Daialog` is dimming the background... i.e. `dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().dimAmount` value is set to `1.0`...

Answer (score 0):

You have set theme for your Dialog

```
Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(this.getApplicationContext(),android.R.style.Theme_Light_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
```

you can customized your theme also.

```
<style name="CustomDialogTheme">
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent_color</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: thanks for your respone.I got a solution fot this.  I deleted this line  from my codings getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);